# Assume that p and q are odd primes and $p \equiv q \pmod {28}$. Show that $(\frac{7}{p}) = (\frac{7}{q})$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol, quadratic-reciprocity, congruence-relations

Assume that p and q are odd primes and $p \equiv q \pmod {28}$. Show that $(\frac{7}{p}) = (\frac{7}{q})$.

Could anyone give me a hint for the solution please?

Comment: If $p\equiv q\mod 28$ then $p\equiv q\mod 7$ and $\mod 4$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner got it thank you it is a trivial question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [quadratic reciprocity law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity). You have:

$$\left( \frac 7p \right) = (-1)^{\frac{7-1}{2}\frac{p-1}{2}}\left( \frac p7 \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left( \frac p7 \right)$$
$$\left( \frac 7q \right) = (-1)^{\frac{7-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}\left( \frac q7 \right) = (-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\left( \frac q7 \right)$$

Now since $p \equiv q \pmod{28}$ we have that $p \equiv q \pmod 4$ and so $\frac{p-1}2$ and $\frac{q-1}{2}$ have the same parity. Thus $\left( \frac 7p \right) = \left( \frac 7q \right)$ if and only if $\left( \frac p7 \right) = \left( \frac q7 \right)$. However the last equality is trivial, since $p \equiv q \pmod 7$.

Comment: why did you put a negative sign in the power in the first line instead of putting 3?

Comment: @hopefully I'm not sure why. Anyway you can completely ignore that term, as after all $(-1)^3 = -1$